# Watch the WWDC replay stream

Tags: discussion

The live link is at http://www.apple.com/apple-events/june-2013/ should have a replay version posted in a bit. The replay will also be posted under Apple TV's Apple Events section for quite some time.

Comment: but no one's hanging out in chat to discuss it. alas.

Answer (score 2):

This was posted so that we could have an announcement on the community bulletin. We can edit and reuse this next year unless it causes grief to anyone.

Comment: Well, Community◆ bumping this might be a form of grief. I'm upvoting to keep that from happening again. :-(